# Find document with URI pattern match

Tags: mongodb

My collection consists of API URI endpoint info.  I want to be able to pass a URI as a search string into MongoDB, and find the document that matches the URI pattern.

For example

If I pass "/api/name/jason/profile"

I want to search all the documents in my collection for the doc that contains...

URI:"/api/name/(:*)/profile"

(:*) being a wildcard.

Any suggestions on how I should go about doing this?

UPDATE:::
To clarify...

That would work if I had a simple pattern that didn't really change. But the problem is that I might not know which part of the URI is dynamic .. So what I really need to do is compare my URI with a collection of documents that all contain different URI patterns so my documents might have patterns like so...

```
/api/name/{id}/ 
/api2/event/{id} 
/api/events/{from_date}/{to_date}
```

What I want to do is find a document that best matches a URI pattern that I pass.

So if I pass "/api/events/20170102/20170330" then Mongo will return the document that has a "uri":"/api/events/{from_date}/{to_date}" pattern.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex

Comment: What's the collection name and on which fields should the query search for? From your example I assume it should look for documents in the `profile` collection on the `name` field, right?

Comment: yeah...   collection is apis and field is uri

Comment: @AlexBlex - I assumed it would be regex..  but I'm a bit new to Mongo, and I see that there are items like regex components and they talk about regex vs. pattern syntax...  I just didn't know if there was a "preferred" way to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :-

```
db.collection.find( { 'URI': { $regex: '/api/name/*/profile', $options: 'i' } } );
```

Comment: In short, this would work if I only had a single URI pattern to compare against.  But my issue is that I have a few hundred patterns to compare against (this is for a pretty big API platform)